# Validation naming conventions? C#

Tags: c#, standards

Very simple question, but I want to start using a consistent naming convention for validation methods and I can't think of the best way!

Do people tend to use IsDataValid() style? or are there any others that are more descriptive and meaningful?

Cheers

Comment: Are you doing something like this: http://conditions.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends what your validation method does.

If it returns a Boolean, then probably starting with `Is` and ending with `Valid` is a good place to start. Using `is` for Boolean calls generally leads to readable code in `if` statements.

If your validation method throws an exception, then I'd usually start the method name with something like `Check` instead.

However, also worth considering (as methods should usually use verbs) is beginning the method name with `Validate`. The `Is` style is generally more applicable to properties.

Answer (score 9):

As with anything involving naming conventions, there's no such thing as a *right* answer, but there's a lot of common problems with validation methods that lend themselves towards a certain approach, namely:

- If everything is OK, you typically only need the boolean status of the validation.
- If there are problems, you usually need to know details about the problem.
- You usually want objects to have similar approaches to validation.

One approach I've found to be useful is to have a seperate validator class for each model object I want to validate that implements a common `IValidator` interface, usually with the following methods:

- A constructor that takes the object to be validated in.
- A property named IsValid(), that validates the object, returns a boolean, but stores specific errors in private variables so validation doesn't need to be recalculated when you do want the errors.
- A property named ErrorMessages, that validates the object (if it hasn't been validated yet), and returns a list of errors with the object.

This allows a pretty natural usage within your business logic:

```
BusinessObject obj = new BusinessObject();

// populate fields

BusinessObjectValidator objValidator = obj.GetValidator();

if (objValidator.IsValid) {
    obj.Save();
} else {
    foreach (var errorMessage in objValidator.ErrorMessages) {
        // output message
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like Microsoft likes this approach too. Something similar (IValidatableObject) was introduced back in [Asp.Net MVC](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1083/aspnet-mvc-self-validation-model-objects), and they've kept it around in [.Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#ivalidatableobject).  I also prefer the validation logic to be in the class being validated; less chance for them getting out of sync as the codebase ages.

Answer (score 1):

> Do people tend to use IsDataValid() style?

I typically use the 'Is' MethodName style when the method returns a single Boolean value. It is perfectly acceptable in terms of naming. A lot of times data validation is done within the Set of a Property rather than a method so in this case you don't need to change the property name to indicate it validates the data set on it.

Here is a link that gives some general naming guidlines which you might find interesting as well:

**Naming Guidelines:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(v=vs.71).aspx