# "Validation that might throw exception" - Naming convention and semantics

Tags: validation, exception, naming-conventions, standards

If you **validate** something in code you can either work with a **return value** indicating that something is wrong or you can **throw an exception**. In my controller I have Exceptional validation like this:

```
 void DoSomething()
 {
     Validate();  // throws exception if something is wrong
     .....
 }
```

I wonder if there is a common naming convention that implies that an exception is thrown when something is wrong so that I don't need to add the comment `// throws exception if something is wrong` and distinguishes from `if (!IsValid())`

Note: [validation-naming-conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575291/validation-naming-conventions-c-closed) does not answer my question.

**Update after accepting the answer: What I have learned from this Question**

- AssertValid() or VerifyAndThrow() are good names (tnx @hacktick)
- Validation must distinguish with a context (warning or error)
- Exceptional Validation is good as a kind of **Contract** or second line of defense that might exist only in Debug mode to ensure that the surrounding `if (IsValid(...))` does not miss something (tnx @ Cody Gray)

Comment: Any reason why you've chosen to throw an exception? It doesn't seem at first blush that a failed validation is a truly exceptional case. What's wrong with return values?

Comment: I used Exceptional Verification as a second line of defence in case the If-s are missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you would use:

```
// for a validations that returns just plain yes no (true|false). in the case of a property use caching for the last validationresult.
bool IsValid

// for a validation that returns a list of errors of some sort (messagelist, id list, custom objects, whatever you need).
object Validate();

// validates and throws an exception if one or more error occured.
void ValidateAndThrow();
```

Also make sure to consider if you need warnings of some kind. For example if you validate your registration DTO model and want to warn a user if the password is weak but do not want to prevent the user from saving it if he chooses to.

Comment: thanks **ValidateAndThrow()** is simple and intuitive even for non native speakers. In the meantime i found Microsoft-c++-mfc-Method **AssertValid** that only exists in debug build. Im am not shure which is better. The validation context (Warning, Error) is also a good point.